# Script to Change italic font into a standard font in JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, twitter, fonts, userscripts

I'm using Chrome and on Twitter it doesn't show the Arabic font while in italic, especially in the Bio section on the person's profile. So I inspected the bio element and I found out that if I modified the CSS elemnt .bio and erased the "italic" it will show the bio perfectly.

[Before](http://i42.tinypic.com/259vh55.png)

[After](http://i41.tinypic.com/35jzfup.png)

I need a userscript to do that for me. I'm not good at Java Script and so I was wondering if anybody can help me.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a stronger CSS rule, not JavaScript:

```
.bio {font-style:normal !important;}
```

You can use the [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) plugin to add styles to pages, similar to the way GreaseMonkey adds scripts.

Comment: and where do I insert that so it automatically does its job everytime I go on twitter ??

Comment: Like he said with "Stylish" plugin. If you enter his code it will be always applied when you visit twitter. But you have to set this only for twitter.com